# Confirm paymentform library is loaded

Tags: square

Is it possible to reference and load the library using

```
 jQuery.getScript('https://js.squareup.com/v2/paymentform')
```

This would allow me to deal with a load failure if the library didn't load. I'm asking since getScript should execute the library after loading but it's not.

Comment: Do you have access to `SqPaymentForm` in the callback you're passing into `.getScript()`?

Comment: What I am trying to accomplish is when there is a glitch with a users WIFI connection and the library doesn't load that javascript retries loading it again.

Comment: If you wrap your `.getScript()` call in a function, you could recursively call it in the callback passed to `.getScript()`. That way, in your callback you can handle the `.fail()` event if it timed out and just retry.